# Java & Compile-Time Constants

Tags: java, performance, constants

Will a `static final` variable of a primitive or `String` type, that is assigned a value at definition be considered as a **REAL** compile-time constant by the Java Compiler?
Will such a variable gain the performance bonus a compile-constant has in other languages, say C++?

Are enums of primitive or `String` values get treated like constants by the compiler?

From what I understand, it is always good to substitute variables with constants **when it doesn't effect workings of the script** and so I wonder at the empty meaning for the `const` keyword in java.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regarding constant strings it really doesn't matter much if it substitutes it with a reference to the constant or uses the final variable. It is still going to be an object reference pointing to the exact same constant string.

Comment: 15.28 Constant Expression (and 4.12.4 final Variables), JLS 3rd Ed, is remarkable straightforward on this. Enums and nulls are not primitives and not compile-time constants. http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#5313 (and http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#10931)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they're compile-time constants. For example, the code

```
private static final boolean DEBUG = false;

...

if (DEBUG) {
   // some code
}
```

will be compiled to bytecode which doesn't even contain the code inside the `if`. It will be removed by the compiler.

And you have to recompile all the classes referencing the constant if you decide to change its value.

Note however that it's only the reference that can't be modified. The content of the object (if it's mutable), can be changed. For example, the content of the array or StringBuilder in the following code may be modified:

```
// don't do this:
public static final String[] seasons = new String[] {"Spring", "Summer", "Autumn", "Winter"};
public static final StringBuilder someBuffer = new StringBuilder("foo");
```

Your question about enums doesn't make sense. There is no enum of primitive or STring. Each enum defines its own class.

Comment: Well, how many classes may refer to a private static final? ;-)

Comment: Well, technically, a lot: the class where it's defined and all its inner classes :-)

Comment: Can an enum be a compile-time constant under any circumstances?

Comment: No. What would you expect to do with enums that could be done only if they were compile-time constants?

Comment: I didn't mean only compile-time constants, just asking if they could be.

Answer (score 1):

The Java compiler doesn't optimise much but it does do constant expression evaluation of final primitives and some common optimisation on Strings and enums.  Whether this is a good thing or not is rather subjective. e.g. Say you have a constant in a library

```
public static final int MY_CONST = 1;
```

this will be inlined.  However if you try to change this either in code or a runtime using reflection, this will not work unless you re-compile everything which depends on it.  Given most of Java has dynamic late linking, this is easily forgotten and breaks dynamic linking to some degree.

IMHO, if they designed the compiler again today, they wouldn't do this optimisation, they would let the JIT do this instead.

Comment: This may have proper use in closed-source projects — some debug-only code that makes reverse engineering easier will never appear in compiled .jar file, for example...

Answer (score 0):

The **const** keyword is not used in java. It was held aside as a reserved keyword when the language was created, but was not implemented.

Enums and predefined string values like so:

```
String foo = "foo";
```

ARE considered compile time constants, they are assigned and immutable.

You can read more about compile time constants in the Java Language Specification:

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#5313

Comment: `foo` is not a constant, but `"foo"` is an immutable literal.

Comment: According to the JLS, Strings are constant: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#5313

Comment: However fields and local variables which reference a String are not automatically constants.