# Why do we need compile time constants in Java?

Tags: java

Why do we need them, ie what are the benefits of using them ?

Finally, is it right that compile time constants need to be final, but not necessarily static ?

Comment: Well, if it weren't final, there's not much way it could be a constant... :P

Comment: Because if there was no compile time constants you would have asked why there is no compile time constants in Java :D

Comment: See [Java & Compile-Time Constants](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655691/java-compile-time-constants?rq=1)

Comment: for optimizations in compile and runtime. For code clarity warnings ("This variable can't be null here"). Also to understand what it does etc. read this: http://www.coderanch.com/t/454384/java/java/compile-time-constant

Comment: @MarounMaroun - haha. but seriously, what are the things they offer besides a common name for a constant ? Performance ?

Comment: @Useyourhead The link jlordo provided should answer your question.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer -looks like you are the only person who responded with a sane answer. Everyone is high as hell :)

Comment: @Useyourhead Well thats because everybody wants you to use your head before asking. Type that question into some search engine and be enlightened.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer Did you notice that his name is useyourhead before you wrote "to use your head"?

Comment: @MarounMaroun Of course.

Comment: I believe it is partly for performance but also because you can use constants in places you can't use fields. You can use `case A:` if `A` is constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of compile time constants is decided at compile time only. Consider this

```
public static final String s = "abc";
```

Here, variable `s` refers to a string object that is a compile time constant and this will be created in the memory at the time of class loading. In case of string objects, there will be only one string created `abc` in the constant pool, so whenever there are multiple string constants whose value is `abc`, then they will refer to the same `abc` object in the constant pool memory.

The advantage of this can be that only one  objects need to be created that can be referred by multiple reference variables.